# deploying rails angularjs app with capistrano

Tags: angularjs, capistrano, bower

I have a rails app with angularjs front end. I am trying to deploy the app using capistrano. here are my steps (keep in mind I am a novice in both capistrano and angular)
1. instal nodejs and npm on server
2. run the following task in deploy namespace. (I have .bowerrc and bower.json in rails root directory)

```
namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      task :bower_npm_install do 
        on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
          within release_path do 
            execute :npm, "install"
            execute :bower, "install"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The error I got is

> Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'angular-cookie' with type
>   'application/javascript'

Seems that the task :bower_npm_install is not running before angular-cookie is accessed. Here are my questions

1. How can I run the task
2. is it the correct approach to deploy app with angular?
3. Are there any other steps I need to run?